# Claimed Bitcoin before high security

Tags: wallet-recovery, paper-wallet, crypto.com

I claimed a paper wallet on Crypto.com before the high security went into affect.  I am unable to get into my account and access my currency.  Pass phrases, I.D., s.s., were not part of the process at the time.  How do I claim what is mine?  I still have the paper wallet.

Comment: Have you tried "[sweeping](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-sweep-private-keys-from-other-bitcoin-clients)" your paper wallet into a wallet such as [Electrum](https://electrum.org)?